# Three.js Collision detection of spheres with THREE.Raycaster

Tags: three.js, webgl, raycasting

For my project I need collision tests in Three.js. In my CollisionDetection class I'm trying to get a Raycaster to work. And I found some weirdness that I can't explain and can't find a way around:

My CollisionDetector works fine for Cubes.. but when I use Spheres instead, it doesn't give me the same results – Am I wrong to expect the same results as for the cubes? Or do I miss something else?

Here is my Code:

```
var renderer, camera, scene;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    var container = document.getElementById("scene");
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;        

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(width, height); 
    camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( 0, width, 0, height, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.z = 300;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.add(camera);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var geometry =  new THREE.SphereGeometry(10,16, 16);
    //var geometry =  new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10, 10, 10 );

    var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xFF3333} );
    var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xFF3333} );
    var material3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xFF3333} );
    var material4 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xFF3333} );
    var material5 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xFF3333} );

    var element1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material1 );
    var element2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material2 );
    var element3 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material3 );
    var element4 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material4 );
    var element5 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material5 );

    element1.position.set(200,200,0);
    element2.position.set(200,100,0);
    element3.position.set(200,300,0);
    element4.position.set(100,200,0);
    element5.position.set(300,200,0);

    scene.add(element1);
    scene.add(element2);
    scene.add(element3);
    scene.add(element4);
    scene.add(element5);

    var CollisionDetector = new CollisionDetection();   
    CollisionDetector.addRay(new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0));
    CollisionDetector.addRay(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0));
    CollisionDetector.addRay(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0));
    CollisionDetector.addRay(new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0));

    CollisionDetector.addElement(element1);
    CollisionDetector.addElement(element2);
    CollisionDetector.addElement(element3);
    CollisionDetector.addElement(element4);
    CollisionDetector.addElement(element5);

   document.onclick = function(){
        CollisionDetector.testElement(element1);
    };
}

function CollisionDetection(){
    var caster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    var rays = [];
    var elements = [];

    this.testElement = function(element){
        for(var i=0; i<rays.length; i++) {
            caster.set(element.position, rays[i]);
            var hits = caster.intersectObjects(elements, true);
            for(var k=0; k<hits.length; k++) {
                console.log("hit", hits[k]);
                hits[k].object.material.color.setHex(0x0000ff);
            }
        }
    } 
    this.addRay = function(ray) {
        rays.push(ray.normalize());
    }
    this.addElement = function(element){
        elements.push(element);
    }
}
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Or best, see for yourself how it behaves: http://jsfiddle.net/mymL5/12/

On Click every element hit by a ray should turn blue and all hits are registered in the console.
Note the (imho) weird console output for spheres.
Also, why is the lower sphere not hit while the upper is?

You can switch between Cubes and Spheres by Commenting/Uncommenting **lines 19/20**

Can anyone help me? What am I not getting?

PS: I'm new to Three.js, so I'm probably being dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework-related, I am only going to provide some tips.

Your scene is rendering upside down because your args to orthographic camera are incorrect.

Your sphere is bigger than your cube.

Your rays are hitting the north and south poles of your spheres exactly. What is different about those points?

The `material.side` property tells `Raycaster` which side(s) of a face to consider the "front".

Your fidde example is running an old version (r.54) of three.js.

three.js r.58

Comment: Thanks for the tips! The only thing I really don't get is what the difference is between the north/south pol and any other point on the sphere.. shouldn't I get always the same result when a ray hits? No matter where it hits?

Comment: Also, I edited the fiddle to make it more correct: http://jsfiddle.net/mymL5/11/. It's still r.54 because fiddle only provides that one out of the box.. the behavior in r.58 is the same.

Comment: Set `material.wireframe = true`, and see if you can figure out what is happening at the poles. Your `OrthographicCamera` params are still not correct. Is is rendering right-side up?

Comment: Well it seems that on the poles there is a "gap" where there's no actual face and the corners of the surrounding faces do not close perfecly.. so the ray just passes through? Shouldn't that be handled by Three.js? I mean who's expecting that? And more practical: How can I test for this case, to avoid a wrong result?

Comment: Is the ray passing through or hitting mutiple faces around the pole?

Comment: Both happens (depending on if its south or north pole).. But I can only test for this if I know there is an object. But im doing the Raycasting exactly to figure out **if** there is one or not.. so I won't find any if its exactly above me.. its like im having a dead angle (or two).. do you have any suggestions on how to know if there is an object directly above the tested one?

Comment: I updated the fiddle again.. depending on the window size, you can actualy **see** the gap.. http://jsfiddle.net/mymL5/14/

Comment: Screen pixels are not very precise, don't jump to conclusions. You need to have one ray and one sphere so you can understand what is happening. Print out the sphere vertex coords. Reduce the number of faces on your sphere to make it easier to understand. If there is a gap, the coords should show it.

Comment: I played with fiddle and rotated the sphere to some non-trivial angles, it still was missing some of the spheres. It really shows some weird behavior, I must admit.

Answer (score 0):

Increased spheres size.
Rotated spheres by some non-trivial angle (so they don't get hit right in the N/S pole).
Now it works? :P

```
var geometry =  new THREE.SphereGeometry(20,17, 17);

element1.position.set(0,0,0);
element2.position.set(0,100,0);
element3.position.set(100,0,0);
element4.position.set(0,-100,0);
element5.position.set(-100,0,0);

element1.rotation.set(0,0,10);
element2.rotation.set(0,0,10);
element3.rotation.set(0,0,10);
element4.rotation.set(0,0,10);
element5.rotation.set(0,0,10);
```

Still, ray test should be aware of the hitting exact vertex or edge of the triangle, so that might be considered as a place-to-improve for Three.js.

Comment: But what if I have some kind of planetary system.. so rotating every element will just move the blind spot of my collision detection.

Comment: Add invisible bounding box for ray testing? Planets aren't that close to each other so they won't collide and intersect.

Comment: Well its more like a molecular structure I want to build, where the elements attract each other.. But I will consider the invisible bounding box.. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could even try with tetrahedron bounder.
But, if the bounding object is going to be invisible, you could rotate it no mater how to get ray testing right, so you could go with a spheres also.

Comment: Yea, I'll just create an invisible sphere with the same values but slightly rotated, so one of the two will always be hit.

Answer (score 0):

I filed an issue about this in the Three.js repository:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3541